# GetHicon from a 16 COLOR bitmap returns an image with less colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have:

```
Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());
```

using a bitmap that has only 16 colors (not 16 bit depth), but the icon that's created has less colors than the bitmap.

How do I solve this?

Comment: It is the conversion to 16 colors that makes it *look* like the icon has a lower resolution.  Inevitable from mapping 16 million colors to 16, any kind of subtle shading or anti-aliasing effect is going to turn into a blob.  There's no other mousetrap in the .NET framework to get a better result, only ever create icons with an icon designer program.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand what you're saying. The original has only 16 colors. Why shouldn't it return the exact same image, but as an icon?

Comment: I see that I wrote "resolution". I meant - less colors.

Comment: The colors you used probably don't match the colors in the palette used for the icon.  So you lost some colors.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Is there a set palette? Or can I control it? (I used MS Paint to create the image.)